# Tem como fazer Upload de um Favicon em Formato .ICO

Tags: php

Olá, estou tentando fazer um upload para o BD de um arquivo .ICO, achei que se somente incluísse a extensão .ICO no arquivo de UPLOAD bastaria, mas puro engano meu.

Ai faço a pergunta:

Tem como fazer Upload de um Favicon em Formato .ICO?
Se tem como poderei adaptar o arquivo de upload abaixo:

```
    <?php

    if(isset($_POST['favicon'])){

    //INFO IMAGEM   
    $file = $_FILES['favicon'];
    $numFile = count(array_filter($file['name']));

    //PASTA
    $folder = '../upload';

    //REQUiSITOS
    $permite = array('image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif', 'image/ico');
    $maxSize = 1024 * 1024 * 5;

    //MENSAGEM
    $msg = array();
    $errorMsg = array(
        1 => 'O arquivo no upload é maior que o Limite de finido em upload_maxsize',
        2 => 'O arquivo ultrapassa o limite de tamanho em Max_file_size',
        3 => 'O upload do arquivo foi feito parcialmente',
        4 => 'Não foi feito o upload do arquivo',
    );

    if($numFile <= 0)
        echo 'Selecione uma Imagem!!';
    else{
        for($i = 0; $i < $numFile; $i++){
            $name = $file['name'][$i];
            $type = $file['type'][$i];
            $size = $file['size'][$i];
            $error = $file['error'][$i];
            $tmp = $file['tmp_name'][$i];

            $extensao = @end(explode('.', $name));
            $novoNome = rand().".$extensao";

            if($error != 0)
                $msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> ".$errorMsg[$error];
            else if (!in_array($type, $permite))
                $msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> Erro imagem não suportada!";
            else if($size > $maxSize)
                $msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> Erro imagem ultrapassa o limite de 5MB!";

            else{
                if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $folder."/".$novoNome))             
            $favicon = $_FILES['favicon'];

                $update = mysql_query("UPDATE pagcabecalho SET favicon = '$novoNome' WHERE codigo = '$codigo'");

            if($update == ''){

echo "<script language='javascript'>
window.alert('Erro ao atualizar Imagem!!!');
</script>";
}else{
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; URL= ../admin/interna.php'>
<script language='javascript'>
window.alert('Imagem atualizada com sucesso!');
</script>";
}}}}}
?>
```

Desde já agradeço a atenção de todos a minha duvida.

Comment: A primeira pergunta que me surge é para que é que queres meter um favicon na base de dados?

Comment: Estou tentando criar um painel administrativo de Site, e gostaria de oferecer ao usuário, a opção de poder inserir o favicon que desejar. Mas já descobri que não necessariamente tenha quer um arquivo com extensão .ICO, consegui descobrir que com .JPG também funciona. Mas obrigado pelo seu interesse.

Comment: Murilio mas também podes gravar as imagens numa pasta e guardas apenas o caminho para a pasta na base de dados...